# Java - a better alternative to javax.ws.rs.QueryParam for a long list

Tags: java

I'm currently utilizing javax.ws.rs.QueryParam to do a POST to an endpoint in an old application that doesn't have org.springframework.web.bind.annotation package.
I'm used to using org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody to send complex data. But I'm not seeing anything in javax.ws.rs. similar to the org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody.
What I want to do is to be able to post hundreds of ids to an endpoint, and using QueryParam for it is not appealing - I'd end up with a very long url of this format:

```
https://localhost:8000/rs/sample/active?ids=180&ids=250
```

Ideally, I'd find something similar to org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody in basic java libraries to send a list of ids that could be in hundreds.
Any ideas how i could do this with java/javax libraries?

Comment: For Java-/JakartaEE applications, there is normally one unannotated parameter in the parameter list. the request body is implicitly bound to this one. See, for example, [the official JavaEE 7 documetation of `javax.ws.rs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html).

Comment: What @Turing85 said. Unlike Spring Boot, in JAX-RS you need to annotate everything that is *not* the request body, with annotations like `@HeaderParam`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam` or, as a form of catch-all, `@Context`. The latter is needed for types like `HttpServletRequest`, or JAX-RS types like `HttpHeaders`.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you, yes, I see that just by defining a model class representing the body I want to use and referencing that new class in my service method does the job.